# Django datetime field - convert to timezone in view

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime

I have a Django model with a **datetime** field. When it is saved, the datetime field stored in my **DB** lose the timezone info, so it's saved as a **naive** datetime. In general this is not a problem since Django converts it back automatically when rendering the datetime field in the template.

But what about the view? Let's say I need the string representation of the datetime server-side. Depending on summer/winter time, my timezone could be GTM+1 or GMT+2, what makes the things more difficult.

So how do I apply the **local tz conversion in the view**? I have tried several ways with pytz. No success, ome entries are converted to GMT+1 and others to GMT+2 :(

Eg.

```
system_tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')
local_dt = item.created_at.astimezone(system_tz)
local_dt = system_tz.normalize(local_dt)
```

Additional info:

- Django 1.8.7.
- settings.USE_TZ = True
- MySQL
- Why am I doing this? Because I have a table which loads all its rows on demand through AJAX. I need to prepare the datetime values with strftime() before send them to the client.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

start with this:

```
from django.utils import timezone

local_dt = timezone.localtime(item.created_at, pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
```

To convert to UTC+1:

```
from django.utils import timezone

local_dt = timezone.localtime(item.created_at, timezone.get_fixed_timezone(60))
```

- [How to get local time in current timezone (2nd question)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/timezones/#usage)
- [localtime()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime)
- [get_fixed_timezone()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.get_fixed_timezone)

Comment: Same result. Some entries are converted to GMT+1 and others to GMT+2. Maybe because my timezone is DST, but they all should be GMT+1 nowadays.

Comment: pisapapiros 2016-03-20 (before time change) is UTC+1, 2016-03-30 (after time change) is UTC+2 http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin.

Comment: Oh, that's it! I tried too many things I finally ended up messing my mind, but the output was correct! Thanks Vladimir for helping to sort it out

Answer (score 15):

There's no need to use `django.utils` to convert between timezones :

```
berlin = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')
local_dt = item.created_at.astimezone(berlin)
```

Yet if you usually work with just one timezone it is convenient to store it in `settings.TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'` and then

```
local_dt = timezone.localtime(item.created_at)
```

will convert it to your localtime.

Comment: Then you will need to import `pytz`.

Comment: @ar2015 pytz is ~10 times lighter than django, it is a standard de facto lib for timezone operations. And it is a dependency of many popular libs (including django).

Comment: That's a good reason.

Answer (score -1):

django provides **timesince** function in **django.utils.timesince** module

i use this

```py
from django.utils.timesince import timesince
since = a_datetime_object
return timesince(since)
```

you can also pass a second argument to be a reference instead of datetime.now()

Possible outputs are
"2 weeks, 3 days" and "1 year, 3 months" etc