# Convert datetime field to specific timezone

Tags: python, django

i have set

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_TZ = True
```

i have a datetime field called "updated_at", i want to covert the value in this field to indian timezone.How can i do that? indian timezone is "Asia/Kolkata"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django datetime field - convert to timezone in view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072711/django-datetime-field-convert-to-timezone-in-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pytz to achieve this,

```
import pytz

datetime_with_new_tz = object.created_at.astimezone(pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata"))`
```

Also, i recommend you that always save datetimes as UTC, then you can convert it in the view or in your template as you need

Ie, if you want to convert the timezone in your template, you can use `tz`

```
{% load tz %}
{{object.created_at|timezone:"Asia/Kolkata"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default timezone.

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
```